# When intersections of trajectories in Poincare sections are possible?

Tags: classical-mechanics, computational-physics, phase-space, chaos-theory, poincare-recurrence

If we get intersections of some "trajectories" in non-standard 2D Poincare sections, that have been obtained from numerical integration of Hamilton equations for autonomous system in 2D coordinate space (4D phase space), is it an error or there could be an alternative explanation?

The numerical calculation of Poincare section have been done by Mathematica NDSolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the system's (configuration) space has $2$ dimensions, then its phase space has $4$ dimensions (say, position $\mathbf{x}$ and corresponding momentum $\mathbf{p}$) and a typical Poincaré section has $4-1=3$ dimensions. In this case, a 2-D plot is a projection and crossing in it usually don't have any special meaning, since they don't necessarily correspond to crossings in the full phase space.

When they do indicate crossings in phase space, though, such crossing points must correspond to periodic orbits, otherwise the uniqueness of the solution of differential equations will have been violated.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! Seems, there happens overlapping of systems's dimensionality definitions leading to misunderstandings.